# python raw_input prompt skipped when first run

Tags: python, raw-input

I tried looking through the forums for an answer to this but I think it is too specific to my case.

I am writing an image reduction script using python and pyraf. It prompts the user if certain IRAF tasks need to be completed using raw_input("Question"). I have one line, pasted below, that is skipped when I first run the script. If I re-run the script though immediately after, it isn't skipped. The script skips this prompt and goes immediately to the next one, so this step in the reduction is completely missed.

Does anyone know why this would occur? Or if this is answered somewhere else already and I just missed it?

```
skyslit=input("Which slit is for sky? Enter 0 if no sky slit: ")-1

for i in range(len(rows)/2):
    if raw_input("Need to combine flats, normalize response and divide from comparisons and science frames?: ") == 'yes':
        ####Making lists of individual slit files and normalized files
        szflat,junk,szflats=listfiles(flats[0][5:-5]+'_s'+str(i+1),beg='z*.')
        szcomp,nszcomp,szcomps=listfiles(comps[0][5:-5]+'_s'+str(i+1),beg='z*.',bias='yes',append='n')
        scrzsci,nscrzsci,scrzscis=listfiles(scis[0][5:-5]+'_s'+str(i+1),beg='crz*.',bias='yes',append='n')
        ####Combine flats into master file
        iraf.unlearn(iraf.flatcombine)
        iraf.flatcombine(szflat,output='sz'+flats[0][5:-5]+'_s'+str(i+1),combine='average',reject='minmax',ccdtype='none',process='no',subsets='no',delete ='no',rdnoise='RDNOISE',gain='GAIN')
        print 'Created Master Flat file: sz'+flats[0][5:-5]+'_s'+str(i+1)+'.fits'
        ####Normalize flat response for each slit
        iraf.noao.twodspec.longslit.response('sz'+flats[0][5:-5]+'_s'+str(i+1)+'.fits','sz'+flats[0][5:-5]+'_s'+str(i+1)+'.fits','Res_sz'+flats[0][5:-5]+'_s'+str(i+1)+'.fits', interac='yes', functio='chebyshev', order='30')
        print 'Normalized Flat response for each slit'
        ####Divide Comps and Science frames by Normalized Flat
        ####Make lists for extracted files
        ccdproc(szcomp,nszcomp,szcomps,flat='yes',flatfile='Res_sz'+flats[0][5:-5]+'_s'+str(i+1)+'.fits')
        ccdproc(scrzsci,nscrzsci,scrzscis,flat='yes',flatfile='Res_sz'+flats[0][5:-5]+'_s'+str(i+1)+'.fits')
        print 'Divided Comp and Science frames by Normalized Flat'

    ####Combine consecutive, normalized Comparison spectra in batches
    c_comps=sorted(glob.glob('nz*.'+comps[0][5:-5]+'_s'+str(i+1)+'.fits'))
    num=[]
    for c in c_comps: num.append(float(c[3:6]))
    sets=[]
    lis=[num[0]]
    n=1
    while n < len(num):
        if num[n]-num[n-1] == 1.: lis.append(num[n])
        if num[n]-num[n-1] > 1.:
            sets.append(lis)
            lis=[num[n]]
        if n == len(num)-1: sets.append(lis)
        n+=1
    l=0
    ####Creating file lists
    complist=''
    compfiles=[]
    while l < len(sets):
        ind=[num.index(n) for n in sets[l]]
        comblist=''
        for n in ind: comblist+=c_comps[n]+','
        iraf.imcombine(comblist[:-1],'nzComp'+str(l)+'_'+comps[0][5:comps[0].index('_')]+'_s'+str(i+1)+'.fits',combine='average',reject='minmax')
        data,h=py.getdata('nzComp'+str(l)+'_'+comps[0][5:comps[0].index('_')]+'_s'+str(i+1)+'.fits',header=True)
        del h['CCDSEC']
        py.writeto('nzComp'+str(l)+'_'+comps[0][5:comps[0].index('_')]+'_s'+str(i+1)+'.fits',data,h,clobber=True)
        complist+='nzComp'+str(l)+'_'+comps[0][5:comps[0].index('_')]+'_s'+str(i+1)+'.fits,'
        compfiles.append('nzComp'+str(l)+'_'+comps[0][5:comps[0].index('_')]+'_s'+str(i+1)+'.fits')
        l+=1

    ####Find wavelength solution
    ####Using the combined comparison files
    if raw_input("Need to find wavelength solution?: ") == 'yes': ##THIS IS WHAT IS SKIPPED!
        for im in compfiles:
            iraf.noao.twodspec.longslit.identify(im,coordli='goodman_hgar.dat',match=10,fwidth=7,thresho=10,niter=1)                iraf.noao.twodspec.longslit.reidentify(im,im,interac='no',coordli='goodman_hgar.dat',nlost=5,thresho=10,match=10,trace='no',overrid='yes',verbose='yes')
            iraf.noao.twodspec.longslit.fitcoords(im[:-5])
            scifiles=sorted(glob.glob('ncrz*.'+scis[0][5:-5]+'_s'+str(i+1)+'.fits'))
            imnum=[]
            for s in scifiles: imnum.append(s[5:8])
            first,last=input("First and last number of science frames that correspond to this Comparison (string). Do not include leading 0.: ")
            for s in scifiles[imnum.index(first):imnum.index(last)+1]: iraf.noao.twodspec.longslit.transform(s,'f'+s,fitname=im[:-5],flux='no')

    ####Subtract sky background if in slit
    if i != skyslit:
        if raw_input("Is sky background present in slit?: ") == 'yes': ##THIS IS WHERE IT SKIPS TO!!
```

This if statement is in a for loop that iterates over images I am reducing. Above is the relevant code surrounding the skipped line. Sorry its so long.

Thank you in advance for any assistance!

Comment: *I can post more of the code if that will help.* yes please

Comment: Please give whole loop code please. (you can ommit irrelevant parts)

Comment: Since the bug is obviously in another line of the code, it’s pretty impossible to find it without seeing that code! A minimum example that still demonstrates the problem would be even better, of course.

Comment: Are you piping anything to this script?

Comment: I cannot actually create a minimum example that reproduces this result which is part of my problem! I will try to show you the relevant parts of my code so its not so long but still shows you what is going on.